# Exclude admin bar from showing avatar customization

Tags: admin-bar

I am customizing the WP avatar (to fit a grid) and do not want the avatar customization to show on the admin bar drop down or in the dashboard or on the site (when the admin bar is visible).

I have excluded the avatar change from the dashboard using this code in functions.php:

```
function foo_change_avatar($class) {
    if(!is_admin()) {
           // avatar customization code
    }
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_avatar','foo_change_avatar');
```

How can I also prevent my customization from showing in the admin bar dropdown when the admin bar is visible on the site?

Comment: Why are you customizing it if you don't want to show it anywhere?

Comment: I am showing the avatar in several places throughout the site. It's easier to exclude the admin bar and dashboard than the several other places in the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `WP_Admin_Bar::add_menus()` class method you will find the actions:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_my_account_menu', 0 );
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_my_account_item', 7 );
```

and the two corresponding callbacks are using `get_avatar()`.

To prevent the avatar changes in the admin bar, we can remove the `foo_change_avatar` filter before these callbacks and then add it again after the admin bar is rendered with the `wp_after_admin_bar_render` filter (it looks like this filter is not documented in the Codex):

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', function(){
    remove_filter('get_avatar','foo_change_avatar');
},0); 

add_action( 'wp_after_admin_bar_render', function(){
    add_filter('get_avatar','foo_change_avatar');
});
```

So this part of the admin menu bar:

[image]

where the `get_avatar()` is used, should be excluded from the changes.

We could also have used the `admin_bar_menu` filter with priority greater than `7` instead of the `wp_after_admin_bar_render` filter.